# Error running Azure emulator: Error 5048

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I just moved from one machine to another, so everything is freshly installed (WIndows 7, VS 2012, SQL 2008, Azure 1.8, IIS) and I am getting the errors:

> Site 1273337584 was disabled because the root application defined for
>   the site is invalid. See the previous event log message for
>   information about why the root application is invalid.

and

> The application '/' belonging to site '1273337584' has an invalid
>   AppPoolId 'ff257d89-eddd-4724-9cbb-66a3f05590ef' set.  Therefore, the
>   application will be ignored.

On my local machine.  Any idea why this is happening? What did I forget to set up?